# What are other uses for the <link /> tag?

Tags: html

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [What does <link> tag do besides including stylesheets?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2082362/what-does-link-tag-do-besides-including-stylesheets)

`<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="example.css" />`

With the link tag we can define a relationship type and mime type, but I've never seen it done. What are some examples of **real** uses for the other [rel attributes](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_link_rel.asp)? What sort of support issues exist?

I'm not sure what we can and cannot do with this tag, how the browser deals with it, etc...

From my own playing around, it looks like I can't read any of the called data via JavaScript, but the browser still deals with the content.

Comment: ... but duplicate :) [What does <link> tag do besides including stylesheets?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2082362/what-does-link-tag-do-besides-including-stylesheets)

Comment: Thanks for spotting the duplicate. I'm closing this.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

RSS:

```
<link rel="alternate" type="application/rss+xml" title="RSS FEED" href="/RSS" />
```

FAVICON:

```
<link rel="shortcut icon" href="/favicon.ico">
```

iPHONE/iPAD ICON:

```
<link rel="apple-touch-icon" href="/apple-touch-icon.png">
```

SEARCH:

```
<link rel="search" type="application/opensearchdescription+xml" title="" href="/search.xml">
```

I am sure there are an infinate number of proprietary uses for this.